# Pass Fortran unlilmited class optional argument down multiple subroutines in a module

Tags: class, fortran, polymorphism, optional-arguments

`main.F90`

```
program main
  use my_module

  real(8) :: a, b

  a = 1.3
  b = 2.4

  call my_subroutine1(a)
  !call my_subroutine2(a)

end program main
```

`test.F90`

```
module my_module
contains

  subroutine my_subroutine1(a, b)
    class(*), intent(in) :: a
    class(*), intent(in), optional :: b
  
    select type (a)
    type is (real(4))
      print*, 'real 4 a (my_subroutine1): ', a
    type is (real(8))
      print*, 'real 8 a (my_subroutine1): ', a
    end select

    if (present(b)) then
      print*, 'b is present in subroutine1'
      select type (b)
      type is (real(4))
        print*, 'real 4 b: ', b
      type is (real(8))
        print*, 'real 8 b: ', b
      end select
    else
    end if

    call my_subroutine3(a, b)

  end subroutine my_subroutine1

  subroutine my_subroutine2(a, b)
    real(8), intent(in) :: a
    real(8), intent(in), optional :: b

    print*, 'real 8 a (my_subroutine2): ', a
    if (present(b)) then
      print*, 'b is present in subroutine2'
      print*, 'real 8 b: ', b
    else
    end if

    call my_subroutine3(a, b)

  end subroutine my_subroutine2

  subroutine my_subroutine3(a, b)
    class(*), intent(in) :: a
    class(*), intent(in), optional :: b

    select type (a)
    type is (real(4))
      print*, 'real 4 a (my_subroutine3): ', a
    type is (real(8))
      print*, 'real 8 a (my_subroutine3): ', a
    end select

    if (present(b)) then
      print*, 'b is present in subroutine3'
      select type (b)
      type is (real(4))
        print*, 'real 4 b: ', b
      type is (real(8))
        print*, 'real 8 b: ', b
      end select
    end if

  end subroutine my_subroutine3

end module my_module
```

When `main` calls `my_subroutine1(a)`, output is

```
 real 8 a (my_subroutine1):    1.29999995231628     
 real 8 a (my_subroutine3):    1.29999995231628
```

However, when `main` calls `my_subroutine2(a)`, output is

```
 real 8 a (my_subroutine2):    1.29999995231628     
 real 8 a (my_subroutine3):    1.29999995231628     
 b is present in subroutine3
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (7): Attempt to use pointer B when it is not associated with a target

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              00000000004072A0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000404897  my_module_mp_my_s          62  test.F90
a.out              0000000000403CA2  my_module_mp_my_s          41  test.F90
a.out              0000000000404984  MAIN__                     10  main.F90
a.out              0000000000402B9E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00007F05EDED2555  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402AA9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

In the second case (calling `my_subroutine2`), why does `my_subroutine3` think the optional argument is present?

I understand that I can do something like this in `my_subroutine2`

```
if (present(b)) then
  call my_subroutine3(a,b)
else
  call my_subroutine3(a)
end if
```

but with all `b`'s being an optional dummy argument in all 3 subroutines, this is not required as supported by `my_subroutine1`.

Is using `class(*)` variable as **optional** dummy argument causing this problem? If that's the case, why does `main` calling `my_subroutine1` work without an error?

Comment: Please use the `-g` compiler option to get a meaningful backtrace. Use `-fcheck=all` for gfortran or `-check` for Intel to get compiler checks. Also, be aware that `real(8)` is not portable, even if it is not causing your current problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: Your code runs without any crash for me, both gfortran and ifort. Please tell us 1. your compiler version, 2. your compiler options and all commands you run. 3. your OS version. I also do not get the `b is present in subroutine3` message.

Comment: I am using CenOS 7 with intel/18.0.5.274. I updated the output message with `-check` option.

Comment: I just tried intel/19.0.5.281, intel/2020.2, intel/2021.3.0, and gnu/9.2.0 . They all ran successfully.

Comment: It may be a bug in the old Intel version.